# How can this async url response checker be cleaner/faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, url

```py
with open('things.txt') as things:  
    urls = [url.strip().lower() for url in things]

async def is_site_404(s, url):
    async with s.head(f"https://example.com/{url}") as r1:
        if r1.status == 404:
            print('hello i am working')

async def create_tasks(urls):
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        for url in urls:
            if len(url) >= 5 and len(url) < 16 and url.isalnum():
                task = asyncio.create_task(is_site_404(s, url))
                tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

while True:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(create_tasks(urls))
```

Hi, this is a basic asynchronous url response checker that I created and it's pretty fast, but I'm wondering if there is any way to get more requests per second with the base of this code. I have it designed so that it runs forever and just prints whenever there is a 404 in this example basically. I'm pretty new to python and coding in general and I would like some guidance/advice from anyone who has more experience with this kind of thing.. maybe there is an aiohttp alternative I should use that's faster? ANY advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question so the title states what your code does since reviewers would usually wanna see that first. This is mentioned in [ask]. I would've done this for you, but since it's your question I think you can choose the most appropriate title

Answer (score 3):

Overall, your code looks pretty decent. The functions are doing what they should be (`create_task` shouldn't be running the tasks as well), coroutines are gathered after aggregation.

I'd suggest a few things to make it more readable (and maintainable)

### `if __name__` block

Put script execution content inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. Read more about why [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/1190388).

### Variable naming

While you follow the PEP-8 convention on variable naming, the names still could use a rework, for eg. `session` instead of just `s`.

### URL or path

URL refers to "*Uniform Resource Locator*", which is of the form:

```
scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

You are dealing with only the `path` here, scheme and authority sections have been fixed as `https://example.com/`. This is again naming convenience.

### Gather vs create

You are creating as well as gathering tasks in `create_tasks` function.

### Type hinting

New in python-3.x is the type hinting feature. I suggest using it whenever possible.

---

#### Rewrite

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

HOST = "https://example.com"
THINGS_FILE = "things.txt"


def validate_path(path: str) -> bool:
    return 5 <= len(path) < 16 and path.isalnum()


async def check_404(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, path: str):
    async with session.head(f"{HOST}/{path}") as response:
        if response.status == 404:
            print("hello i am working")


async def execute_requests(paths: list[str]):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for path in paths:
            if validate_path(path):
                task = asyncio.create_task(check_404(session, path))
                tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    with open(THINGS_FILE) as things:
        paths = [line.strip().lower() for line in things]
    while True:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(execute_requests(paths))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This can be further rewritten depending on the data being read from file, using a map/filter to only iterate over validated `path`s in file etc. The above is mostly a suggestion.

Comment: thank you for the insight, really appreciate it and will apply this stuff in the future.

Comment: @humid Why haven't you updated the title yet?